# Select next int value in a column excluding an array of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find a way to get the next free 'Id' of a table, but the result should consider an array.

I'm trying something like this, but without success.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(MAX(idTable), 0) + 1 AS maxId
FROM Table
WHERE someColumn = 123
HAVING COALESCE(MAX(idTable), 0) + 1 NOT IN (777, 778, 779)
```

This code will return to me the value 777, but I need the result to be 780, cause its the next 'Id' not in the array (777, 778, 779)

Note that none of the values 777, 778, 779, 780 exists in this column

Comment: [Bad habits: putting `nolock` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). NoLock is bad in general, but catastrophic when you are trying to get the max id - you need a full table lock.

Comment: Thank you for the advise, I will fix this

Comment: Its not clear what your question is, nor what your issue is. Please provide sample data and desired results. Your code as posted looks roughly OK (aside from the lock hint). I imagine you don't need `coalesce` because you won't have nulls in that column will you?

Comment: The column can have nulls, I will fix this someday, but just got access to this old project and I dont have the time right now, so the coalesce is temporarely needed. Also just edited my question so I hope to be more clear now.

Comment: If your list of values was just 777,779, would the next value then be 778?

Comment: Yes, the next value should be 778 in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can try statically adding the values you want to exclude using `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(MAX(idTable), 0) + 1 as maxId
FROM (
  SELECT idTable FROM [Table]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT idTable FROM (VALUES (777, 778, 779)) X (idTable)
) X
WHERE someColumn = 123;
```

If this code could ever be run concurrently you would need to consider a table locking strategy.